# How to plot histogram from array in Python?

Tags: python

So I have a list of 256 elements in it, and each is a frequency of the corresponding list index. For example, in [a0, a1.... a255], a0 is the frequency of 0, a1 is the frequency of 1,... and a255 is the frequency of 255. I want to plot a histogram with 0, 1, ... 255 on the X axis, and the frequency on the Y axix. How do I do that in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib's [bar chart](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) for that purpose. In your example, you'd have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bar_width = 1. # set this to whatever you want
data = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1])
positions = np.arange(4)
plt.bar(positions, data, bar_width)
plt.xticks(positions + bar_width / 2, ('0', '1', '2', '3'))
plt.show()
```

which results in the following plot:
[image: Bar chart Python]

Comment: do you know how to do that with plt.hist?

Comment: I don't think plt.hist can do what you want given the frequency array; you need to have the array from which the frequencies are calculated in order to use it. But why don't you want to use a bar chart?